# Cannon get reducer to work in index.js import for Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I'm pulling my hair out over this, I can't figure out what the issue is, and I know it's something simple.

When my index.js reducer is set to the below, it works fine:

```
let defaultState = {
    card: null
}


const mainReducer = (state = defaultState, action) => {
    if(action.type === "CHANGE_CARDS") {
        return {
            ...state,
            card: action.card
        }
    } else {
       return {
        ...state
       }
    }
}

export default mainReducer
```

However, when I try to import it from another file, it breaks.

This is the revised index.js:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { LibraryReducer } from './LibraryReducer'
import { LikeReducer } from './like.reducer'



export default mainReducer = combineReducers({
    card: LibraryReducer
})
```

This is the reducer that's imported from another file:

```
let defaultState = {
    card: null
}


export function LibraryReducer(state = defaultState, action){
    if(action.type === "CHANGE_CARDS") {
        return {
            ...state,
            card: action.card
        }
    } else {
       return {
        ...state
       }
    }
}
```

This is my index.js from my actions folder:

```
import axios from "axios"

export function loadCards(){
    return(dispatch)=>{
        return axios.get('http://localhost:4000/reports')
                .then(response => {
                    dispatch(changeCards(response.data))
                })
    }
}

export function changeCards(card) {
    return{
        type: "CHANGE_CARDS",
        card: card
    }
}

export function createLike(like){
    return(dispatch)=>{
        console.log('got here', like)
        return axios.post('http://localhost:4000/likes/add', like)
                .then(response => {
                    dispatch(setLike(response.data))
                })
    }
}

export function setLike(like) {
    return{
        type: "ADDED_LIKE",
        like: like
    }
}


export function countMore(count) {
    return{
        type: "ADDED_LIKE",
        count: count
    }
}
```

This is my cards component where I'm rendering the information:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import {Collapse,CollapseHeader, CollapseBody, AccordionList} from 'accordion-collapse-react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
// import * as actions from '../actions'
import { loadCards, createLike, changeCards } from '../actions'
import LikeUnlike from './LikeUnlike'



class Card extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    value = this.props.loadCards()
  }

  render() {

    console.log('in card', this.props)

    const titleStyle = {
      backgroundColor: '#edeeef',
      fontWeight: "bold",
      color: '#454647',
      fontSize: 12,
      left: 8,
      fontFamily: 'Ionicons',
      top: 10
    }

    const descMarkStyle = {
      left: 6,
      top: 4,
      fontFamily: 'Ionicons',
      color: '#454647',
      fontSize: 13
    }



    return (
      <View style={{position: 'relative'}} >
        { 
          this.props.card != null ?
            this.props.card.map((v,i) => {
              return(
              <View key={i}>
                <Collapse >
                  <CollapseHeader>
                    <View
                      style={{
                        backgroundColor: '#edeeef',
                        height: 38,
                        postion: 'absolute',
                        borderBottomWidth: .5,
                        borderBottomColor: '#black'
                      }} 
                    >
                      <Text style={titleStyle}>
                        {v.title}
                      </Text>
                    </View>

                  </CollapseHeader>
                  <CollapseBody>
                    <Text style={descMarkStyle}>{v.summary}{'\n'}</Text>
                    <Text style={descMarkStyle}>{v.analysis}</Text>
                  </CollapseBody>
                </Collapse>

                <View
                  style={{
                    position: 'absolute',
                    right: 4
                  }}
                >
                  <LikeUnlike
                    like={v.like}
                    id={v._id}
                  />
                </View>
            </View>
              )
            })
         : <Text>{''}</Text>
        }
      </View>
    );
      }

}

function mapStateToProps({ card }) {
  return {
    card
   }
 }

 export default connect(mapStateToProps, { loadCards, changeCards })(Card);
```

I don't think the issue is in the component, because it loads correctly in the initial implementation of the code in the index reducer.

Comment: Can you explain what the **2** exports in `export default mainReducer; export default mainReducer = combineReducers({card: LibraryReducer})` are meant to do?

Comment: Sorry, I went back and edited it the post. I made a mistake on the initial post. What is now in place is an accurate representation.

Comment: please try to return "state" at default switch (and not a new object). It's validated for combineReducers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is since you are using combineReducer you need to specify which reducer you are using when you mapStateToProps and since in your combineReducer you set that name of the reducer to card you are adding a nested card value to your props and you are trying to map an object in your component.  What errors are you getting?  Console log this.props.card and you will probably see an object.  So in your map you would need to map this.props.card.card or in your mapStateToProps add the nested card value maybe like so:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    card: state.card.card
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to return state, not a new object, by default. It's validated at combineReducers:

```
export function LibraryReducer(state = defaultState, action){
    if(action.type === "CHANGE_CARDS") {
        return {
            ...state,
            card: action.card
        }
    } else {
       return state
    }
}
```